# Illusory Reality physics & damage question

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, illusion

Ignoring rules for fun via house ruling or assuming the [School of Illusion wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/wizard#SchoolofIllusion)'s Illusory Reality feature (PHB p. 118) can do damage through indirect means: What is the highest point you could drop a 20' thick metal meteor from, and what would the result be?

The object remains real for 1 minute, so the goal is to place it at a height where it can reach it's highest velocity and hit the ground within that time frame.

Lastly, what would the damage be?

Comment: No problem!  Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange!  For 5e stuff, you can use the tag dnd-5e and it'll reference itself.

Comment: There is definitely a learning curve to it all.  Most important thing to remember here: ask a specific question that doesn't have much bases on opinions.  If it is a question that comes down to an opinion, tack on as many limitations to your question as possible, so it's as close as possible to only being able to have a single answer.  Stack Exchange is quite different from most forums, and tries to cut down on unneeded discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Physics typically doesn't mesh well with D&D rules, sadly, but based on XGTE, max fall damage is 20d6 (1d6 per 10 feet fallen, to a maximum of 20d6), which I would assume is if you are falling or something is falling on you. As for fall rate, XGTE says:

> When you fall from a great height, you instantly descend up to 500 feet. If you’re still falling on your next turn, you descend up to 500 feet at the end of that turn. This process continues until the fall ends, either because you hit the ground or the fall is otherwise halted.

If you wanna go by physics, I believe you fall roughly 600 feet in the first six second (the first round), and about 1000 every round after, assuming an average human in size, terminal velocity, and all other such physics is the same. In that case, max damage would be 100d6, still doing 1d6 per 10 feet (in this case, 1d6 per 10 ft/s).

Comment: Doesn't falling damage normally max out at 20d6? That's for a person falling, not something falling onto a person, admittedly.

Comment: @TripSpace-Parasite Yes, 20d6 is typically max, as noted in the first paragraph. I was simply offering another option, as this seems to be a house-rule question.